# execute a function only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a function which executes on click event, but the thing is that I want it to execute only once.

The function that get's executed on click represents a google map plotting to an targeted element. The function looks like this :

```
Cluster.prototype.initiate_map_assembling = function(target, latitude, longitude) {
    var canvas = $(target).children();
    var coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    var options = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: coordinates,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map($(canvas)[0], options);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coordinates,
        map: map
    });
};
```

And I'm running it on `click` event like this :

```
Cluster.prototype.initiate_google_maps_action = function() {
    var self = this;
    return $(this.maps_wrapper_class).each(function(index, element) {
        var canvas = $(element).parents().eq(3).find(self.map_canvas_wrapper_class);
        return $(element).on('click', function(ev) {
            var latitude = $(element).attr('data-latitude');
            var longitude = $(element).attr('data-longitude');
            self.initiate_map_assembling(canvas, latitude, longitude);
            ($(canvas).hasClass('selected')) ? $(canvas).removeClass('selected') : $(canvas).addClass('selected');
            ev.preventDefault();
        });
    });
};
```

What I want to achieve is stop the plotting each time I click the button, because it's only needed once since I'm only hiding the container div and not destroying it. So how could I do that ? I tried with temporary variables added when the function executes ( and setting it as true after the first time and as false when initiated ) and returning false if the temporary variable is true, but with little success as I could not return false inside the plotting function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.one()`.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

As per OP's explanation: there's always the possibility to define more than *one* click event for an element.

So you can define one with `.one()` and the other with `on()` as you already do, putting the code to run only once in the first.

Comment: Yes, but the click event must occur more than once ( there's an class added or removed each time you click ), so how could I use it ?

Comment: Define TWO click events. One to run once with .one() and the second to run always, toggling the class

Comment: you can set some attribute of element on click and next time you can check the attribute

Comment: I think binding two events is better for me :) Thanks @Cranio for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

you could bind click only once like:

```
$(document).one('click', function(e) {
    //do your code here
});
```

OR

```
$('#someBtn').click(function(){    
    if ($(this).attr('data-once')!='already_clicked' ){
        //your code here
        $(this).attr('data-once', 'already_clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: The second way is *expensive*. Manipulating the DOM when you can simply manipulate a variable is asking for bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

Two choices:

1. Use two event handlers: one defined with `one`, the other with `on`
2. Use a counter in the closure.

Something like:

```
var counter = 0;
return $(element).on('click', function() {
    counter++;
    if ( counter > 1 ) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah , without looking at the code, you can always use a counter. Once the event occurs, increment your counter variable and just make a check for that everytime. easy as pie.

Comment: You don't have to count each time, just increase the first time you run. Then afterwards , just test.  if (!counter) { do_something(); counter++) }