# Allow only one action per click JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [execute a function only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135932/execute-a-function-only-once)

i have this bit of code and i would like the DIV insideframe to move just once, and it works if i click with an interval of time.

if i make many clicks at once, it will move endlessly, not only once :/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".arrow").click(function(){
        pos = $("#insideframe").css('margin-left');
        pos = (pos.substr(0, 3));
        var posi = parseInt(pos);
        if(posi < -23 ){
            die();
        }else if(posi > -20 ){
            $("#insideframe").animate({
                marginLeft: '-=230'
                }, 800 );
        }
    });
});
```

**How can i make it trigger just once?**

Comment: So if I got you right clicking multiple times is allowed but it should only trigger if no animation is running. Is that correct?

Comment: Even though it's almost the same problem, i can't even undertand the code inside that question you pointed out. I am sorry for being a noob. For all that matters, Omar Jackman gave me an answer that is not present on the question you referred to.

Comment: Ghommey, yes. That's it. Omar Jackman gave me an answer that works pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add data to the div when the click event occurs and check for it on subsequent clicks.

Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".arrow").click(function(){

        //Check here if clicked already and return if so
        if($(this).data('clicked') == 'yes')return;
        $(this).data('clicked', 'yes');

        pos = $("#insideframe").css('margin-left');
        pos = (pos.substr(0, 3));
        var posi = parseInt(pos);
        if(posi < -23 ){
            die();
        }else if(posi > -20 ){
            $("#insideframe").animate({
                marginLeft: '-=230'
                }, 800 );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked very well! Thank you very much. Waiting 2 minutes so i can take it as the right answer

Answer (score 1):

You could do `$(".arrow").one('click', function(){...}`. That will let the action happen only once, but you'll have to rebind the click when you want to allow clicking again.

Also check out [this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) plugin.

Comment: Thank you G_M, i don't understand the bind and unbind thing yet :P, but i will read about it.