# JavaScript .click() in for loop only executes once

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I'm trying to **simulate a click on various links** in a website that uses them to expand sections. The developer did not bother to include a "expand all" and there are at least 200 buttons I don't want to click, so I figured I would use **JavaScript**. However any other ideas are welcome.

The links I'm trying to simulate a click on are defined as:

```
<a id='a_link_1' href=...> ... </a>
<a id='a_link_2' href=...> ... </a>
<a id='a_link_3' href=...> ... </a>
```

I thought that using something like this on Google Chrome's Developer Console would work:

```
var level_one = [
    'a_link_1',
    'a_link_2',
    'a_link_3'
];

for (var i = 0; i < level_one.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(level_one[i]).click();
}
```

The problem is that **it only works on the first link**. If I change the order of the links, still it will only work on the first one. I actually tried setting a timer for a little bit thinking that would solve the problem but it didn't.

**Why doesn't it activate all the links and what would be the right way to do it?** Thanks!

In case you want to test it out, the website is: http://www3.inegi.org.mx/sistemas/saic/ (it's in spanish).

---

**Edit:**
@chiliNUT's answer was the most useful to me, so I'll put it here since I can't mark it as the accepted answer because it was not submitted as one.

To summarize,

```
clickables = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="javascript:"]'); 
for (i in clickables) { clickables[i].click(); }
```

will retrieve all objects that have a link associated to them starting with 'javascript' (which is used to trigger the expansion links). The `for loop` actually simulates a click on them, one by one (be careful! You may end up simulating clicks on things you don't want to).

That's it. Thanks to @chiliNUT for providing that solution.

Comment: i can't replicate this, not to mention there are no links on that page called "a_link_1", "a_link_2", "a_link_3", so I can't reproduce the issue, so I can't help you without some more info :)

Comment: running this piece of code to try and trigger every single click event worked fine, so i would need more info about the specific links you are trying to activate: `clickables=document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="javascript:"]'); 
for (i in clickables)
{ 
clickables[i].click(); 
}`

Comment: The page provided does not contain those links

Comment: Could the browser/javascript engine be causing the script to end because an anchor tag (the first one) was clicked? I'm not certain enough to post it as an answer, just a maybe?

Comment: The following link might be helpful for your problem.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135932/execute-a-function-only-once

Comment: @chiliNUT your code actually is pointing in the right direction, but it doesn't expand all the sections. After I execute it a couple of times it start having a weird behavior and doesn't continue expanding the remaining sections. It also opens various other links that I can probably filter out.

I'm inclined to take it as the accepted answer.

Comment: it was just a sample, since I don't have enough information to fully diagnose your issue

Comment: @chiliNUT and @Stephn_R are right. I changed the link names because they are very big and would just clutter the question. I believe that the actual links that open the different sections begin with `P`. An example would be `<a id="P0_AA_DinamicGridGrupoVariables" href="javascript:DemandLoadNodeSaic('DinamicGridGrupoVariables', '0_AA', '0_AA','', 'saic2009.USP_Grupos_Variables_2009_Nuevo'); guardaCadena('DinamicGridGrupoVariables,0_AA,0_AA,,saic2009.USP_Grupos_Variables_2009_Nuevo');" title="Expandir tema">...</a>`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery :

```
        $(level_one.map(function(e){return '#'+e}).join(',')).each(function(e,index){
                 setTimeout(function(){$(e).trigger('click')},index*1000)
});
```

- `a#a_link_1` will be triggered immediately (0 timout)
- `a#a_link_2` will be triggered after 1 second(1000 millisecond timout)
- `a#a_link_3` will be triggered after 2 second(2000 millisecond timout)

.....

- `a##a_link_n` will be triggered after (n-1) second

---

## NOTE

- `level_one.map(function(e){return '#'+e}).join(',')` equivalent to : `'#a_link_1,#a_link_2,#a_link_3'`

Comment: This code shows me the link information on the console, but doesn't actually expand the sections. Thanks, though.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below jQuery code,

```
 jQuery.each( level_one, function( i, val ) {
      $( "#" + val ).click();
 });
```

Comment: How is that any different to the OP (other then being very much less efficient)? (At least format the code correctly…)

Comment: This code is not working. It will not trigger any of the links in that website. Thanks, though.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use jQuery

```
for (var i = 0; i < level_one.length; i++) {
    $("#"+level_one[i]).trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Comment: This code is not working. It doesn't trigger any of the links. Thanks, though.

Comment: @otrenav can u create a jsfiddle so that we can make changes and check